# Can I have a named lambda function as variable inside a class and try to call the named lambda from main function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class convert
{
    public :
        int n;

        convert( int number)
        {
            n = number;     
        }
        auto showbits() =[](){
            cout<<"showbits called "<<endl; 
        };

};

int main() {
    convert c(10);
    auto val = c.showbits();
    return 0;
}
```

1.I am getting following error 
 error: invalid pure specifier (only ‘= 0’ is allowed) before ‘]’ token

Comment: The parenthesis after `showbits` are in excess (that wouldn't be enough to have it working, however)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a lambda as a member because lambda are "strange" objects and you can only declare them with `auto` (there's no way to spell the type of a lambda expression), however `auto` non static members are not allowed.

No real reason for that except that they decided so (there are formally a lot of reasons, but each of them would also apply to other uses of `auto` that are instead allowed, so IMO they're not an explanation).

May be it's something will change in the future when someone else will be in the committee.

You can circumvent the problem by using an `std::function` wrapper for the member.

```
struct Foo {
    std::function<double(double)> square = [](double x) { return x*x; };
};
```

Comment: Or you could just make it a static member, because there's basically no reason for a class-scoped lambda. It can't capture `this` or member variables, so it's really just a needlessly verbose way of writing a static member function.

Comment: @NicolBolas: why having per-instance a lambda member doesn't make sense to you? It's like a function pointer but it's better because it can have state. Unfortunately in C++ implementation the lambda type is tied to the body and not to the interface (and this makes them a lot less useful than in other languages), but wrapping them in `std::function` solves part of the problems.

Comment: "*it's better because it can have state*" 1) His example didn't have state. 2) Any state for said lambda could be in the object itself and therefore have a name and logical meaning for people reading the code, as well as appropriate copy/move behavior as necessary. 3) If it doesn't have state, then it takes up space in the object needlessly.

Comment: @NicolBolas: C++ lambdas are indeed quite weak as the type is tied to the implementation body and not to the interface. Wrapping them up in `std::function` object is mandatory in most cases (and even this is not free from problems because `std::function` sort of "hides" the signature and this creates problems for example with overload resolution).

Comment: You seem to be missing the point. Whether lambdas are "tied to the implementation body and not to the interface" is irrelevant, because for all useful purposes `static void showbits() {cout<<"showbits called "<<endl;}` is exactly equivalent to the lambda in question. Even if the `auto` usage worked, or if lambda types worked differently, there's no reason to use a lambda when a regular function would do just fine.

Comment: @NicolBolas: a non static member can be changed on a per-instance basis. If the lambda has a `mutable` internal state this can make a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213512/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-6502).

Comment: my intension is to make c++ have functions as variable  hence used named lamda to act as variable and class act as body to hold the named lamda .i can also change the nonstatic mutable member as accoding to the instance created using parameters .This intension can be satified normal c99 by creating object and I want the utility function more readable by having a name trying to have do it advanced c++ way